# id and name attributes of HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

In HTML, the name attribute may be used for the elements *a, applet, form, frame, iframe, img, and map*. The *name* attribute and the *id* attribute may be used in HTML to identify document fragments. XHTML documents must use *id* instead of *name* for identifying document fragments in the aforementioned elements. In fact, the *name* attribute for these elements has been deprecated in the XHTML 1.0 specification. Then how do they replace the requirement of name attribute in XHTML? Because, for some tags, radio buttons, etc, name attribute will be useful, when a radio button clicked from multiple radio buttons. So, how does XHTML handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name attribute is **not** deprecated for `<input>` elements (such as radio buttons) in XHTML. It's only deprecated for those elements that you list.